# Async signalR abort call

Tags: javascript, asp.net, websocket, signalr, signalr.client

I am using [SignalR javascipt client](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.JS/jquery.signalR.transports.common.js) in my asp.net application. In my application all the abort calls are sequential and blocking further execution of my JavaScript. In signalR code, i observed that there is a flag for making asynchronous abort call.

[image]

I observed that the default value of async variable inside the ajaxabort method is always false in IE, Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

- Why my abort calls are sequential in chrome and IE. ( not in firefox and safari). Is this expected?
- Am i doing something wrong?
- What are the side effects if i hard-code the async flag to always true?

**Update:**

There is a piece of code in signalR which sets the async property.

```
 var asyncAbort = !!connection.withCredentials && firefoxMajorVersion(window.navigator.userAgent) >= 11;
```

Where does the value "connection.withCredentials" is coming from? For me it is always undefined and so my asyncAbort is always false. This makes my long running abort call blocking everything in chrome and IE. Note: I am not using any cross domain calls.

[Refer Github ticket](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2357)

Comment: you can use keyword `debugger` as a breakpoint in your js code to check again